# Replicate lines in text file according to a column value

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file with a column containing text/data followed by an abundance column, e.g.

> Car 3
>
> Apple 2

In order to subsample these columns I would like to replicate each text column by the amount of the abundance column, e.g.

> Car 1
>
> Car 1
>
> Car 1
>
> Apple 1
>
> Apple 1

Any idea how to accomplish this with for example awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question properly you could do this

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<$NF;i++)print $1,"1\n"}' file
```

Found a shorter way

```
awk '{while($2--)print $1,"1\n"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 awk '{ for (i=$2 ; i ; i--) printf "%s 1\n",$1 ; } ' < text
```

where

```
- `for (i=$2 ; i ; i--)` is a loop that starting from second field value decrease to 1
- `printf "%s 1\n",$1`  print first field with a 1
```

Comment: Dont need to redirect using `<` as awk takes files as args. I do like how you looped though :)

Comment: @Jidder absolutly no need, this is juste given as a sample.